# How to calculate the gravitational field from trajectories?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, projectile

I have a question about numerical simulation. At first I was pretty sure that It should exist some well-established state of the art techniques to solve it, but It seems I don't have the exact keywords because I didn't find anything in the literature.

In a euclidean space, given some object's trajectories (subject to gravity only) and their masses, can you name numerical methods to infer/guess/interpolate the value of the gravitational field anywhere?

If it is a multiple solutions problem, which constraints are usually given to extract physical solutions? (smoothness, density distribution, quantity of matter ...)

Comment: I do not see a question about numerical simulation. What you are asking is if there is a way to reconstruct the gravitational field in a region, provided you have some trajectories of bodies with known masses, i.e., provided that the gravitational field is known on a finite set of lines. The possibility of using numerical simulation is not an essential ingredient.

Comment: check out the GRACE mission.